# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - November 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the second edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for November 2017

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      330
2   Monomeeth                  280
3   grgarside                  190
4   bmike                      160
5   Scot                       120
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 650.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/month/apple/2017-11-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   bmike                    101
2   klanomath                 94
3   Allan                     80
4   grgarside                 70
5   Monomeeth                 51
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 663
2   bmike                     290
3   LangLangC                 288
4   creidhne                  234
5   JW8                       202
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     76
2   IconDaemon                49
3   fsb                       47
4   Scot                      41
5   grgarside                 37
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                  211
2   Monomeeth                 99
3   pjc90                     78
4   Scot                      55
5   IconDaemon                52
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     72
2   Scot                      28
3   grgarside                 27
4   pjc90                     21
5   JMY1000                   16
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     42
2   fsb                       37
3   IconDaemon                25
4   Tetsujin                  19
5   pjc90                     18
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    14
2   Scot                      8
3   fsb, grgarside            6
4   Monomeeth, patrix,        5
    IconDaemon   
5   pjc90, Tetsujin           4
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   techraf                  67
2   Allan                    46
3   JMY1000                  21
4   grgarside                19
5   Monomeeth, pjc90         17
```

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why is it better for an iPhone’s battery to NOT close down apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305681/why-is-it-better-for-an-iphone-s-battery-to-not-close-down-apps)

   - Posted by: F.C
   - Votes: **43**
2. [How do I disable or remove the root account created as a side effect from this High Sierra security bug?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307219/how-do-i-disable-or-remove-the-root-account-created-as-a-side-effect-from-this-h)

   - Posted by: Freiheit
   - Votes: **34**
3. [How is iPhone Storage automatically cleared up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305635/how-is-iphone-storage-automatically-cleared-up)

   - Posted by: Silencer310
   - Votes: **14**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Why is it better for an iPhone’s battery to NOT close down apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305681/why-is-it-better-for-an-iphone-s-battery-to-not-close-down-apps/305682#305682)

   - Answered by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **57**
2. [How do I disable or remove the root account created as a side effect from this High Sierra security bug?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307219/how-do-i-disable-or-remove-the-root-account-created-as-a-side-effect-from-this-h/307225#307225)

   - Answered by: flindeberg
   - Votes: **33**
3. [How can I have 1805 threads when I only have 4 virtual CPUs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304995/how-can-i-have-1805-threads-when-i-only-have-4-virtual-cpus/305015#305015)

   - Answered by: Basil Bourque
   - Votes: **24**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why is it better for an iPhone’s battery to NOT close down apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305681/why-is-it-better-for-an-iphone-s-battery-to-not-close-down-apps)

   - Posted by: F.C
   - Views: **11,506**
2. [How can I have 1805 threads when I only have 4 virtual CPUs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304995/how-can-i-have-1805-threads-when-i-only-have-4-virtual-cpus)

   - Posted by: YellowPillow
   - Views: **4,739**
3. [How do I disable or remove the root account created as a side effect from this High Sierra security bug?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307219/how-do-i-disable-or-remove-the-root-account-created-as-a-side-effect-from-this-h)

   - Posted by: Freiheit
   - Views: **4,402**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Techraf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/145449/techraf)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [F.C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/263760/f-c)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [F.C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/263760/f-c)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In November our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 471 flags with an average handling time of 12 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 186 comments
- deleted 281 posts
- closed 178 posts
- edited 249 posts
- created 163 posts
- created 479 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: And [my hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303371/165931) is off to you, Monomeeth, for this amazing review of the month.

Answer (score 7):

I want to say, even with the "most" reviews being easy to measure, I'm most proud of the *quality* of the reviews, edits, posts and comments that all are true community moderation here.

Some of us get to hand a diamond after our names for a while, but without everyone's work this community wouldn't be nearly as vibrant as it is.

Kudos and thank you whether you did one quality post / review or dozens.

Comment: I have to totally second that. Having only been a Moderator for a brief period, I have to say that the amount of moderation that goes on was a real eye-opener for me. Now, more than ever, I really appreciate the efforts of all users who take the time to edit/review/flag posts. While this report generally only recognises the top 5, the actual number of contributors is so much greater than this, and every one of them helps to make this site what it is. A big thank you again! :)

Comment: No, thank you for your dedication and hard work. I'm just flagging a couple things for review here, nothing like what you're doing.